# IS there anyway to read underlying data in an Excel pivot table in R

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table

I have an excel workbook with a Pivot table using an embedded connection to a DB that I do not have access to. I would like to be able to read the underlying data into R or Python.

I can do this by double clicking the total in the pivot table and saving the result as a file and reading that file. However, I would like to fully automate this as there are multiple spreadsheets so I would have to complete this step multiple times. Also, not an issue yet, but if/when the underlying data exceeds excels row limit, this option would no longer work.

Is there a way to get to the underlying data another way?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)